# @JsonProperty not working (Weblogic 12.2.1 and Java 8)

Tags: java, json, spring, weblogic12c

I'm having a problem where the JsonProperty annotation to change the name of a variable is not being honored. Here is the example app
https://github.com/derrylvarghese/problematicjson

I am converting the following JSON to POJO and then converting it back to JSON

```
String json = "{\"response\": {\"companyname\": \"ABC Company\",\"issn\": [{\"format\": \"paper\",\"val\": \"0018-9480\"},{\"format\": \"online\",\"val\": \"1557-9670\"}]},\"teststring\":\"testing me out\"}";

    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    WrapperObj record = mapper.readValue(json, WrapperObj.class);
    ObjectWriter writer = mapper.writer();
    writer.writeValue(response.getOutputStream(), record);
```

I am expecting the 'val' in the 'issn' object to show up as 'value' since i have a @JsonProperty("value") applied on the 'val' field.
Here is the output json (edited for brevity).

```
    issn: [
          {
          format: "Print ISSN",
          val: "0018-9480"
          }
          ]
```

If i were to create an Issn object and do a record.getResponse.setIssn(setMyObject), the json output shows the proper JsonProperty tag. I am linking to a sample project that will show this if anyone is interested. (git link: https://github.com/derrylvarghese/problematicjson)

**Update**
Seems like since i annotated my POJO field with `@JsonProperty("value")`, the incoming JSON field should also be called 'value'. All this while i was seeing 'val' in the output because i had a catch all List field into which all the fields were going. I removed that JsonAnyGetter field and now my 'val' field does not show up.

Comment: I slapped together a quick unit test and the output was as expected, `val` was written as `value`. Do you have a code sample of your serialization? As a side note you don't need to annotate the getter and the field.

Comment: As @Leon, I can't reproduce.

Comment: You might have imported the wrong `JsonProperty` annotation class or you might be using the wrong JSON serializer, i.e. one that doesn't care about the `JsonProperty` annotation. Provide more code, in particular the imports of th `Isbn` class and the configuration of the JSON serializer.

Comment: @codo This code used to work fine in a Java 1.6 and Weblogic 10 environment. Now i am trying to migrate the same code to Java 8 and Weblogic 12. The Jackson imports are import `com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;` I will try out a unit test case in a separate java project but i am sure that will work fine. THe code that converts this to JSON looks like `ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
   ObjectWriter objectWriter = objectMapper.writerWithView(HtmlView.class); objectWriter.writeValueAsString(record) `

Comment: Can you attach the source for HtmlView?

Comment: Also check for class loader problems. If you have two sets of the Jackson libraries (e.g. one in a shared directory of Weblogic, the other one in your .war file), you could have the same effect.

Comment: @Codo this is what i am thinking. a unit test i wrote in the same project works locally, it fails when loaded into the web environment. I have to go digging into what is in Weblogic. I'll report back my findings.

Comment: no luck yet with my research into conflicting class libraries.

Comment: Added update that narrows down the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK so apparently sometime in the past Jackson may have supported one name for serialization and another for deserialization. Not anymore it seems. When i annotate a getter (getVal() ) with @JsonProperty("value"), it expects the incoming json payload to also have "value" (and not "val") eventhough i have a setVal() method.

Answer (score 2):

@Codo say check your import, I used to have the same trouble when in my project few imports mixed library from different providers of Jaxson reader/writer
Check that and I'm sure you'll find your bug.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have added jackson-databind dependency/jar in your project -

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    <version>2.8.0</version>
</dependency>
```